# Check if shared preferences exist in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm saving login data in a shared preferences value set to skip the login if the shared preferences exists.

I'm saving this data with this code here:

```
//Save userdata as SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor loginEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
loginEditor.putString("displayName", displayName);
loginEditor.putString("loginEmail", loginEmail);
loginEditor.putString("loginPassword", loginPassword);
loginEditor.commit();
```

Finaly I want to check at the start of my login activity if the shared preferences `loginPrefs` exist.

How can I do this? Is there a way to ask:

```
//Pseudocode
if (SharedPreferences loginPrefs exists) { //How can I ask here?
  Intent intentMain = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
  LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intentMain);
  finish();
} else {
  //Set the shared preferences
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
//Pseudocode
SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
if (loginPreferences.contains("loginEmail")) { //How can I ask here?
  Intent intentMain = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
  LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intentMain);
  finish();
} else {
  //Set the shared preferences
}
```

Comment: Error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'getSharedPreferences'"

Comment: I'm not using this method. `getSharedPreferences` - you use it. provide more code. or use `context.getSharedPreferences()` , where `getSharedPreferences` - is ,e.g., your current activity

Comment: But my android studio don't know your method?

Comment: `getSharedPreferences()` method is used in Context class. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: Where did you take your code written in the question?

Comment: Hmm but with your answer I need to get the sharedPrefs first as a value before ask in an if statement?

Comment: I mean, this code could be used inside either `Activity` or `Service` class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133303/discussion-between-vyacheslav-and-itsodi1).